# what is the better method to generate initial solution?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have metaheuristic like the Genetic Algorithm when the initial population is well generated that affects the final result. So, what are the used method to generate the initial population like chaos I need other ones?
Can I use another metaheuristic to generate the initial population for the Genetic algorithm?

Comment: As it is not strictly coding related, you may get more help over OR Stack Exchange: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.